# About zeros of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I wonder why the polynomial $x^p-x$ has $p$ distinct zeros in $\mathbb Z_p$ for any prime $p$, i.e. $x^p-x=x(x-1)\cdots(x-p+1)$.
Do I need to expand the polynomial in order to get the conclusion?

Comment: No, you need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is tagged **ring theory**, I assume that OP already knows some group theory.
As $p$ is a prime, every number in {$1,\cdot\cdot\cdot, p-1$} is prime to $p$, hence, [by Bézout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), the set $\mathbb {Z/pZ}=${$1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,p-1$} forms a group under multiplication.
Now this group has order $=p-1$, so every number $x\in \mathbb {Z/pZ}$ satisfies $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p^{Notice}$, [by Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29). And this is equivalent with your result.
*Notice:* One could also see this directly by using [Petit Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_theorem), if there is such a name.

Comment: @YACP It was supposed to connote a similar meaning to a joke. And I suppose that, ordinarily speaking, one leanrs ring-theory after some exposure to group theory. After all, how can one define a ring without the notion of a group?

Answer (score 5):

This will help: See [**Fermat's Little Theorem**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Added: ...as I see @anon suggested!

Point being: You don't need to expand the polynomial!

Comment: Well, we could expand it using Stirling numbers (of the first kind), as their generating functions are the rising/falling factorials (viewed as polynomials). But this a tangent.

Comment: You're correct @anon, I'll revise.

Comment: :+) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Use [little Fermat;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or [Freshman's Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) (a.k.a. [Frobenius map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism)) $\rm\color{#C00}{\,applied\,}$ below

$$\rm mod\ p\!:\,\ f(x)=x^p\!-x\:\Rightarrow\:f(x\!+\!1) = \color{#C00}{(x\!+\!1)^p}\!-x\!-\!1 \,\equiv\, \color{#C00}{x^p\!+1^p}\!-x\!-\!1 \,\equiv\, x^p\! - x = f(x)$$

Hence $\rm\ f(x\!+\!1)\equiv f(x)\ $ so $\rm\ f(p\!-\!1)\equiv f(p\!-\!2)\equiv \cdots \equiv f(1)\equiv f(0)\equiv 0.$

Comment: + Nicely done! $\ddot\smile$